# Uso método static con HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Estoy comenzando a usar HashMap en vez de los Arrays y estoy haciendo un programa donde el usuario hace como que maneja una tpv y tiene que registrar un producto, su precio, stock y ventas. El problema viene en ventas, que no sé cómo coger lo ya guardado para poder operar para que me reste lo vendido a las unidades que hay en stock

```
public static void introducirProducto(Scanner teclado, String codigo, HashMap<String,Productos> listaProductos){
    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    double precio;
    int stock;
    int unidadesV = 0;

    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre de su producto");
    codigo = teclado.nextLine();
    if(listaProductos.containsKey(codigo)) {
        System.out.println("Este producto ya existe");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Introduzca el precio de su producto");
        precio = Double.parseDouble(teclado.next());
        System.out.println("¿Cuántas unidades hay en Stock?");
        stock = Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());

        listaProductos.put(codigo, new Productos(precio,stock,unidadesV));  
    }
}


public static  void ventas(String codigo, HashMap<String,Productos>  listaProductos, Scanner teclado) {
    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    int stock = 0;
    int unidadesV = 0;

    System.out.println("Elija el producto que quiera ");
    codigo = teclado.nextLine();
    if (listaProductos.containsKey(codigo)) {
        System.out.println("Cuántas unidades desea?");
        unidadesV += Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
        if(stock >= unidadesV ) {
            stock -= unidadesV;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No es posible realizar esta operación");
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No existe ese producto");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes?¿Cómo es el método que llama a estos dos métodos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando parte de tu código:

```
Productos producto = listaProductos.get(codigo);

if (producto != null) { // o sea si obtuvo un producto con ese código
    int stock = producto.stock; //aquí ya tienes el stock del producto.
    //o quizás sería stock = producto.getStock();
    System.out.println("Cuántas unidades desea?");
    unidadesV += Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
    if(stock >= unidadesV ) {
        stock -= unidadesV;
     ///aqui requieres actualizar el stock del producto, no se que métodos tengas
     ///pero lo usual sería:
        producto.setStock(stock);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No es posible realizar esta operación");
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println("No existe ese producto");
}
```